# Passing a pointer to a Map in Dart

Tags: dictionary, pointers, dart

Suppose I have this class:

```dart
class A {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  Map<String,int> _map;
  
  A(this.a,this.b,this.c): _map = {'a':a,'b':b,'c': c};
  
  operator [](String k) => _map[k];
  operator []=(String k, int v) {
    if(_map.containsKey(k)){
      _map[k] = v; 
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ' a: $a, b: $b, c: $c, map: ${_map.toString()}';
  }
}
```

I want to be able to access its attributes either by `myObj.a` or `myObj['a']` (something like how it's done in JavaScript). My code works just fine when the attributes are read (so this solution is perfect for an immutable class), but when I try to set new values, I don't get the expected result:

```dart
void main() {
  A a = A(1,2,3);
  a['a'] = 4;
  a.b = 5;
  print(a); // prints: Instance of 'A' a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, map: {a: 4, b: 2, c: 3}
}           //expected: Instance of 'A' a: 4, b: 5, c: 3, map: {a: 4, b: 5, c: 3}
```

Now, I know the error is in the constructor, but I don't know how to assign to the map the reference to `a`, `b`, and `c` instead of copying their values.

Is it possible to pass the pointer of these attributes to `_map` so I can update the values by either `myObj.a = x` or `myObj['a'] = x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to have a single point of truth for the value of `a`/`["a"]`. It's probably easiest to use the map.
That means the `a` getter and setter should access the map instead of the unrelated field.

Maybe something like:

```dart
class A {
  Map<String, int> _map;
  
  A(int a, int b, int c): _map = {'a': a,'b': b,'c': c};
  
  int/*?*/ operator [](String k) => _map[k];
  operator []=(String k, int v) {
    if(_map.containsKey(k)){
      _map[k] = v; 
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError("No variable named $k");
    }
  }
  
  int get a => _map["a"]/*!*/;
  set a(int value) => _map["a"] = value;
  int get b => _map["b"]/*!*/;
  set b(int value) => _map["b"] = value;
  int get c => _map["c"]/*!*/;
  set c(int value) => _map["c"] = value;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ' a: $a, b: $b, c: $c, map: ${_map.toString()}';
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally I prefer the opposite approach of doing away with the map and defining the indexer to return/modify the fields, but it's interesting to see someone post the other direction.

Comment: Both works, I'd probably also prefer the opposite approach if this is the entire problem, but I am assuming that there will be other uses for the map, perhaps in a `toJson` method. (And I'd never write a class like this to begin with, anyway, it's not a well-designed  API. I'f anything, I'd have an `asMap()` method to return a map, not put the `[]` on the class itself.)

Answer (score 0):

All right, I will not comment why you need such implementation :).

But the issue is in []= operator: you are updating map only, not fields of the object. At the same time in toString() you are accessing fields, not map values.

What you could do is update fields in []= operator. But I guess better would be to have data in one place only, not in both: map and fields. So I would just override fields' getters and setters to access data in map.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me address one thing. You will not be able to get Javascript-like behavior with being able to use property references and an indexer interchangeably to access the properties of an object in Dart. The only reason this works in Javascript is that every object in Javascript is itself a hash map of sorts, so property references are effectively converted to map indexers anyway. To do this in Dart, you would need to define some kind of catch-all getter that can dynamically convert property references to indexing operations, and that functionality doesn't exist in Dart (nor, in my opinion, should it).

Now, as far as your specific code, it's not working because in your setter indexer, you are updating the value in the map, but in the `toString` method, you print the values of the fields. In order to get your expected results, you will need to update the fields as well. In fact, there's no reason to have an underlying map at all - just operate on the fields directly.

The problem with that approach, of course, is that you will need to provide a mapping in your indexers for every field in your class, since as I mentioned before, there's no way in Dart to dynamically convert a string to a property reference*.

```dart
class A {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  
  A(this.a,this.b,this.c);
  
  operator [](String k) {
    switch (k) {
      case 'a': return a;
      case 'b': return b;
      case 'c': return c;
    }
    throw ArgumentError('Property name $k doesn't exist');
  }

  operator []=(String k, int v) {
    switch (k) {
      case 'a': a = v; return;
      case 'b': b = v; return;
      case 'c': c = v; return;
    }
    throw ArgumentError('Property name $k doesn't exist');
  }
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ' a: $a, b: $b, c: $c';
  }
}
```

This pattern has the obvious flaw of having to update your switch blocks every time you add or remove a property, but unfortunately, it's the only real option you have.

My real recommendation is to stop trying to force Dart to bend over backward to make it feel more like Javascript. You will never become proficient in a programming language if you are constantly approaching it from the perspective of a completely different language. Just bite the bullet and learn to code in idiomatic Dart and your experience will be a much more positive and productive one.

**: Technically you can use reflection via `dart:mirrors` to dynamically get a reference to a property from a string. However, reflection is disabled in Flutter, and as a general rule it's a bad idea to depend on reflection for a niche feature of your code anyway.*